# How to make two column pivot and other as normal

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 table name class , Student and Religion and below data are as follows

**Class Table**

```
ClassId     ClassName
  1         class-1
  2         class-2
  3         class-3
```

**Religion Table**

```
ReligionId    RegionName
  1           Hindu
  2           Muslim
```

**Student Table**

```
employeeid  StudentName religionid  dateofbirth classid
    1         A               1     1990-12-04    1
    2         B               2     1999-12-04    2
    3         C               2     2000-12-04    1
    4         D               2     1988-12-04    1
    5         E               2     2003-12-04    2
    6         F             NULL    2002-12-04    1
```

How Can I achieve below record from above tables

```
CLASSNAME  HINDU   MUSLIM  Noreligion
  class-1     1     2           1
  class-2     0     2           0
```

You can create the tables from the below scripts

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[class](
    [ClassId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClassName] [varchar](250) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_class] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClassId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Religion](
    [ReligionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RegionName] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Religion] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ReligionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student](
    [employeeid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [religionid] [int] NULL,
    [dateofbirth] [date] NULL,
    [classid] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Student] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [employeeid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[class] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[class] ([ClassId], [ClassName]) VALUES (1, N'class-1')
INSERT [dbo].[class] ([ClassId], [ClassName]) VALUES (2, N'class-2')
INSERT [dbo].[class] ([ClassId], [ClassName]) VALUES (3, N'class-3')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[class] OFF
INSERT [dbo].[Religion] ([ReligionId], [RegionName]) VALUES (1, N'hindu')
INSERT [dbo].[Religion] ([ReligionId], [RegionName]) VALUES (2, N'muslim')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Student] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[Student] ([employeeid], [StudentName], [religionid], [dateofbirth], [classid]) VALUES (1, N'A', 1, CAST(N'1990-12-04' AS Date), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Student] ([employeeid], [StudentName], [religionid], [dateofbirth], [classid]) VALUES (2, N'B', 2, CAST(N'1999-12-04' AS Date), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Student] ([employeeid], [StudentName], [religionid], [dateofbirth], [classid]) VALUES (3, N'C', 2, CAST(N'2000-12-04' AS Date), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Student] ([employeeid], [StudentName], [religionid], [dateofbirth], [classid]) VALUES (4, N'D', 2, CAST(N'1988-12-04' AS Date), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Student] ([employeeid], [StudentName], [religionid], [dateofbirth], [classid]) VALUES (5, N'E', 2, CAST(N'2003-12-04' AS Date), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Student] ([employeeid], [StudentName], [religionid], [dateofbirth], [classid]) VALUES (6, N'F', NULL, CAST(N'2002-12-04' AS Date), 1)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Student] OFF
```

Do it require Pivot table to be use.
I was not able to made the query getting such records.

Comment: Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2005? That is long out of support. Why have you tagged SQL Server 2008 as well (also basically out of support). Which version of SQL Server are you actually using here?

Comment: @Larnu just removed, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more conditional aggregation that pivoting. This gets you the result you're after:

```
SELECT C.ClassName,
       COUNT(CASE R.RegionName WHEN 'Hindu' THEN 1 END) AS Hindu,
       COUNT(CASE R.RegionName WHEN 'Muslim' THEN 1 END) AS Muslim,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN  R.RegionName IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NoReligion
FROM dbo.class C
     JOIN dbo.Student S ON C.ClassId = S.classid
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Religion R ON S.religionid = R.ReligionId
GROUP BY C.ClassName;
```

If you don't understand the syntax, please ask.

*Edit: OP has now stated that there are more religions than just the 2 they provided, and needs to be dynamic. This therefore gives:*

```
--Additional sample row if you wish:
INSERT [dbo].[Religion] ([ReligionId], [RegionName])
VALUES (3, N'Catholic');
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT C.ClassName,' + NCHAR(10) +
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(10) +
                         N'       COUNT(CASE R.RegionName WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(R.RegionName,N'''') + N' THEN 1 END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(R.RegionName)
                  FROM dbo.Religion R
                  ORDER BY R.ReligionId
                  FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,2,N'') + N',' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'COUNT(CASE WHEN  R.RegionName IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NoReligion' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM dbo.class C' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'     JOIN dbo.Student S ON C.ClassId = S.classid' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'     LEFT JOIN dbo.Religion R ON S.religionid = R.ReligionId' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'GROUP BY C.ClassName;';

SELECT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Can we do this without writing Hindu, muslim as text, As there can be multiple religion and every time we cannot write the text

Comment: You'll need Dynamic SQL for that. Your question didn't cover that scope, so I didn't fulfil it. Give me about 15 minutes.

Comment: @miteshjain updated for you. I suggest making sure your questions cover all the scenarios though; this'll mean you get a faster/more correct answer sooner. :)

Comment: I was needing answer fast so I had also added the script so that you all can create table in easy way :-)

Comment: My comment was in reference to the fact that you didn't specify the results needed to be dynamic, @miteshjain . Anyway, the latest version should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Pivot with dynamic columns.  You can have unknown number of Religions

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);    

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ReligionName) 
            FROM Religion c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

Set @sql = '
SELECT  ClassId, '+ @cols + ',[NoReligion] 
FROM
  (
   Select 
     IIf (ReligionName IS NULL, ''NoReligion'', ReligionName) As ReligionName,
     employeeid,s.ClassId 
   From
   Student s INNER JOIN
   Class ON s.classid = Class.ClassId FULL OUTER JOIN
   Religion ON s.religionid = Religion.ReligionId) As src 
   Pivot
(
Count(employeeid) 
FOR ReligionName IN('+@cols+',[NoReligion])
) As pvt'


EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```